# Grep CURL JSON Output

Tags: json, grep

My curl output is

```
{
    "router": {
        "node_id": "ip-1-2-3-4",
        "state": "HEALTHY",
        "message": "OK"
    },
```

I want to get the output as

```
state:HEALTHY
```

How can i get that i'm trying

```
curl -sk https://localhost/router/api/v1/system/heealth | grep -Eo router.*\n.*\n.*\"state\": \"HEALTHY\"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to parse JSON, way easier than `grep`:

```
curl -sk https://localhost/router/api/v1/system/heealth|jq -r .router.state
```